# Splitting string in python using multiple operations in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
selstim = '/Users/folder1/folder2/folder9/Pictures/Set_1/Pos/43et1.jpg'
```

I need to end up with:

```
43et1
```

I tried:

```
selstim.split('/')[-1]
```

Which produced:

```
43et1.jpg
```

I also tried:

```
selstim.split('/,.')[-1]
```

That doesn't get the desired result.

Is there a way to also get rid of the '.jpg' in the same line of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementation using only the standard `os` library.

```py
from os import path

filePath = path.basename("/Users/folder1/folder2/folder9/Pictures/Set_1/Pos/43et1.jpg")

print(filePath) # 43et1.jpg
print(path.splitext(filePath)[0]) # 43et1, index at [1] is the file extension. (.jpg)
```

All in one line:

```py
path.splitext(path.basename(FILE_PATH))[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may just find it easier to use `pathlib` (if you have Python 3.4+) and let it separate the path components for you:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> p = Path('/Users/folder1/folder2/folder9/Pictures/Set_1/Pos/43et1.jpg')
>>> p.stem
43et1
```